# HTML iFrame not working

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Why my code is not working, it is still useful to yesterday. Please , I've no idea on it.

```
<iframe allowfullscreen="" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" height="2000" scrolling="no" src="http://www.google.com" width="100%"></iframe>
```

But it shows on this url with the same code:

```
<iframe allowfullscreen="" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" height="2000" scrolling="no" src="http://www.live3s.com" width="100%"></iframe>
```

.. I really have no idea. Please help me. I want to iframe this url "http://mmfootballtv.wix.com/home#!youtube-links/uzgjx" . Thank you for interesting my problem.

Comment: Check the `X-FRAME-OPTIONS` header.

Comment: Your browser console should have been able to tell you the reason already – so please learn to use it as a debugging tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, below is the reason. In other words the problem is not in your code, there are other google apis which you can use to embed google search, you just need to google it.

P.S. If something is not working as it should you can always hit F12 and check the developer console, that's how i found about the problem.

> about:blank:1 Refused to display
>   'https://www.google.bg/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=pUTEVvKaD4eJ8QeK26n4BQ' in a
>   frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

Answer (score 0):

you can't just put another website form a different domain in an iframe. Because of security reasons this is sometimes blocked. It is called clickjacking. for more information https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking